# Trigger or stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, procedure

I need to update table1.field1 From table2.field2 everytime there is a new entry on table2. I created a trigger that does exactly that :

```
CREATE [dbo].[insert_trg]
on [dbo].[TheCat99]
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
Update therefore.dbo.thecat99
SET factura = (SELECT dbo.pedido.num_factura
                    From dbo.Pedido
                    Where  dbo.thecat99.pedido=dbo.pedido.num_pedido)
WHERE dbo.thecat99.pedido = ( SELECT dbo.pedido.num_pedido
                           FROM dbo.pedido
                           Where dbo.thecat99.pedido = dbo.pedido.Num_Pedido)
AND dbo.thecat99.factura is NULL
END
```

The trigger Works but it's not in production yet.I've been reading about how triggers are bad and evil, but i cant see how can i do this using stored procedures.
Is the trigger a good idea? If not, how can i do the same with a stored procedure?

Comment: Where did you read that triggers are bad and evil, do you have a reference? Using a procedure you need to encapsulate both actions in the procedure and make sure that no one modifies table2 outside of the procedure.

Comment: Triggers aren't inherently evil. Triggers that *ignore* the `inserted` pseudo-table (as here) or fail to account for that table containing 0, 1 or multiple rows are generally broken. There's nothing currently in your trigger to stop it from having to scan *the entirety of both tables* during every insert, rather than being limited by just the row(s) that were inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers are not bad nor are they evil.  They are a great tool (and for some tasks, the only tool) but they do require knowledge and careful use, since they are not as simple to write as they seem at first glance.

As a general rule, Triggers should be as light-weight and effective as possible.
This is because SQL Server will not return control to whoever executed the statement that fired the trigger until the trigger is also completed.

Having said that, your update code could be written like this (that will be more efficient and more readable):

```
UPDATE t
SET factura = p.num_factura
FROM therefore.dbo.thecat99 t
INNER JOIN  dbo.Pedido p ON t.pedido= p.num_pedido
WHERE t.factura IS NULL
```

**However** Since you are not using the `inserted` table, It means that every time any row gets inserted into `TheCat99` all the rows where the `pedido` value matches the `num_pedido` in `Pedido` will be used for the update. There is still room for improvement - using the `inserted` table instead of `thecat99` means you will only be working with the records that was just inserted to the `thecat99` table, so your code will be far more efficient:

```
UPDATE t
SET factura = p.num_factura
FROM inserted t
INNER JOIN  dbo.Pedido p ON t.pedido= p.num_pedido
WHERE t.factura IS NULL
```